# How to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{2x-1}{x+1}\right)^{1/x}$?

Tags: limits

Good evening, everyone! I need some help to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{2x-1}{x+1}\right)^{1/x}$.

I assumed the limit to be "L" and took the natural logarithm on both sides:

$$
\ln(L) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac1x\ln\left(\frac{2x-1}{x+1}\right)
$$

However, now the logarithmic term tends to $i\pi$. So this where I run into trouble. I have no idea how to solve this type of limit. I searched the problem on WolframAlpha and it gave out the solution as $e^{2i-3}$. Perhaps it has something to do with rearranging the logarithmic term to $\ln(2-\frac{3}{x+1})$? Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, this function isn't clearly define when $x$ is small. When $-1<x<1/2,$ the value of the fraction is ambiguous, and $(\cdot)^{1/x}$ is then difficult to define, unless $1/x$ is an integer.

Comment: In particular, when $(2x-1)/(x+1)$ is negative, the natural logarithm you wrote is undefined.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. Something strange : type `Table[{k,N[((2 - 10^k)/(1 + 10^k))^10^k]},{k,1,6}]` Results are real !

Comment: Apparently we're using the definition $x^y = \exp(y \ln x)$ using the principal branch where $-\pi < \operatorname{Im} \ln x \leq \pi$.

Comment: I think it could make a difference whether the limit is taken over real $x$ or complex $x$.